# QnA Maker doesn't show buttons when deployed in MS Teams

Tags: azure, button, microsoft-teams, azure-qna-maker

I have deployed a qnamaker bot to Microsoft Teams but the dialog buttons don't show up anymore.

[In the qnamaker site, the buttons work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmnYV.png)

[In teams, the buttons don't appear ;(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW5cC.png)

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this changes? 
Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

@Ceal clem Are you trying to use Suggested actions? If so, [suggested actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-actions) are not supported in Teams. Could you please try using [Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards) to show the buttons?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure it is suggested actions, it's the "follow-up prompts" that allow you to create a sequential dialog that aren't showing up in teams...is that the same thing?

Comment: Teams only uses cards to show buttons. Could you please try using cards to give a rich UI to the messages?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/how-to/multiturn-conversation#enable-multi-turn-during-testing-of-follow-up-prompts

You need to add this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/qnamaker-prompting) to enable prompts in client.